# How to change multiple columns to one column with a ranking and number count in R?

Tags: r, unique, lapply

I have multiple columns that I would like to change to one column that has a rank and a count column. The columns have an uneven amount of rows.

`Example`

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 |
    1    |    2     |    3     |    4     |
    1    |    2     |    3     |          |
    1    |    2     |          |          |
    1    |          |          |          |
    2    |    3     |    4     |    5     |
    2    |    3     |    4     |          |
    2    |    3     |          |          |
    2    |          |          |          |
```

What i'm trying to do is get one column with all the unique numbers a rank and count column.

Column 1 has all the unique numbers from column 1 to 5. It organized by the ranking.

Ranking is just highers count to lowest count - 2 has the most number in this example 7 and 5 has the least 1. So 2 is rank number 1.

Count is just how many numbers 2 has 7 total numbers 3 has 5 total numbers.

```
Column 1 | Ranking | Count |
    2    |    1    |   7   |
    3    |    2    |   5   |
    1    |    3    |   4   |
    4    |    4    |   3   |
    5    |    5    |   1   |
```

I have tried this for right now. But i have a lot more work to do.

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", header = TRUE, strip.white =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
uniquedel <- unique(df)
write.csv(uniquedel, file = "/Users/uniqueRSA.csv")
```

Whatever help you can give would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I can't seem to find a clear relation between the initial table and the final result. Please try to explain better what you want to do. The code provided does not even try to approach the problem, so it would be best if you try to  give us some code where to start.

Comment: `unlist` `df`, then `table` it and apply `rank`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added some more info to help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since it doesn't seem to matter where numbers are located, you can use `unlist` to just get all the values as a single numeric vector. `table` will then count occurrences for you; you can coerce it into a `data.frame` to give you two of the three columns you want. You can now use `order` to make a `Ranking` column, but since it's a permutation of indices instead of a rank, you'll need to `order` the `order` to get it back in the same order as your rows. All told, where `df` is the original `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(table(unlist(df)))
df2$Ranking <- order(order(df2$Freq, decreasing = T))
```

gives you

```
> df2
  Var1 Freq Ranking
1    1    4       3
2    2    7       1
3    3    5       2
4    4    3       4
5    5    1       5
```

If you want it ordered by `Ranking`, index it by `order(df2$Freq)`. There are lots of other possible ways to go about this, too. `rank` would be really useful, except in base it is only ascending instead of descending, and thus would also take some manipulation.

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(column.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), column.2 = c(2, 
2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA), column.3 = c(3, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 
NA), column.4 = c(4, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("column.1", 
"column.2", "column.3", "column.4"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `rank(-x)` can be used to rank descending.

Comment: @thelatemail Oh, that so simple! I feel dumb now. Honestly, I've been using `dplyr`'s `desc()` helper, but I wanted to keep this all base.

Comment: Plus that lets you do it all in one line: `data.frame(table(unlist(df)), Ranking = rank(-table(unlist(df))))`

Comment: Or `transform(data.frame(table(unlist(df))), Ranking=rank(-Freq) )` to save doing the unlist/table twice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you simply want to tabulate the counts for each integer value in the original matrix, irrespective of the column it occurs in. Then order the table by ranks of these counts.

```
# make sample data, like yours
# note your example contains missing/empty cells
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 4*8, replace=T),ncol=4,nrow=8))

# tabulate and rank, note ranks can be fractional in case of ties
tab <- table(unlist(df))
data.frame(tab,rank(tab))[order(rank(tab), decreasing=TRUE),]
   Var1 Freq rank.tab.
1    1    3       1.0
4    4    5       2.0
2    2    6       3.0
3    3    9       4.5
5    5    9       4.5
```

Note, what you define as *Rank* seems to be the inverse of how R defines it: `x < y <=> rank(x) < rank(y)`. I have answered to the literal phrasing in your question.

You might be tempted to use:

```
# data.frame(tab,order(tab, decreasing=TRUE))[order(order(tab,decreasing=TRUE)),]
```

to reproduce your sample, however this does not handle ties in a good way.

Another option is to use the following:

```
data.frame(tab,nrow(tab)-rank(tab))[order(rank(tab),decreasing=TRUE),]
  Var1 Freq nrow.tab....rank.tab.
3    3    9                   0.5
5    5    9                   0.5
2    2    6                   2.0
4    4    5                   3.0
1    1    3                   4.0
```

using your non-standard definition of rank.

Comment: Thank you all for the help ..... Can you guys give me some advice on what books to read or videos to watch ... I'm trying to get better with R

Comment: @orthoeng2 Check out the [r tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info); it's got loads of great resources on it.

Comment: Sorry orthoeng2, the only book on R/S I have ever read is Venables & Ripley, S Programming, Springer